# Saving Angular Form Data with Node Express and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express

I'm brand new to the MEAN stack and am clearly missing something.  I'm trying to save a character name, and I'm saving blank objects to the database.

partialaddchar.jade

```
div(class="col-xs-4")
                input(type="text", class="form-control input-sm", name="pcname", placeholder="character name", ng-model="form.pcname", required autofocus)
                span(class="help-block") Character Name
                input(class="btn", type="submit", ng-click="addChar()") Go
```

controllers.js

```
    function AddCharCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
  //$scope.form = {pcname: ''};
  $scope.form = {};
  $scope.addChar = function () {
    $http.post('/api/addChar', $scope.form).
      success(function(data) {
        $location.path('/');
      });
  };
}
```

api.js

```
exports.addChar = function (req, res) {
  var newCharacter = new Character(req.body);
  newCharacter.save();
  console.log("character added: " + req.body);
  res.json(req.body);
};
```

The console returns "character added: [object Object]

POST /api/addChar

Then successfully redirects to the character list, with the word Level printed as many times as I've hit save (because I've saved an empty object obviously).

partiallistchar.jade

```
div(ng-repeat='charnode in chardata')
            a(href='/readCharacter/{{charnode._id}}') {{charnode.character + " Level " + charnode.level + " " + charnode.class}}
```

I based this approach on a tutorial and seed, and browsing stackoverflow it seems everyone does this a little differently and attempting a solution would require a rewrite.  I'm a conformist, so if there is a clear best practice and my approach is off, I would appreciate the feedback.

Thanks.

edit -- I am using Mongoose.  I was also able to get it working by specifically referencing req.body.pcname.  I had the impression that this would not be required, especially given that the data being returned is in the form of pcname: value.  I'd appreciate any comments as to how this can be completed without having reference every form field.

```
exports.addChar = function (req, res) {
  var newCharacter = new Character({
    pcname: req.body.pcname});
  newCharacter.save();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  console.log("character added: " + JSON.stringify(req.body.pcname));
  res.json(req.body);
};
```

Comment: need the code in newCharacter.save(); or are you using mongoose?

Comment: Per my edit, I am using Mongoose.  I was also able to get it to work, although I'm sure there's a better way than referencing every form field in the api.  Looking forward to any insight you can provide.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't have experience with mongoose and forms. This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586768/mongoose-form-to-save-model-with-embedded-documents